# removeListener inside for loop ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I'm having trouble removing a mouseover/mouseout listener inside a foor loop.
Let's say I have a menu that on desktop and on hover shows a dropdown, but to open the dropdown I want it on click on mobile. I need to remove the hover on mobile because I don't want it to be doing both. Here's my main function that opens the dropdown:

```
 addChildrenActive(i){  
        if(this.parent[i].classList.contains('b--nav-a__list-group__list-item--is-active')){
            //removes class to hide the dropdown         
        } else {
            //adds class to show the dropdown
        }
    }
```

- note that this function is receiving i as a param.

on the other hand, I have the function responsible for the listeners:

```
 navbarInteraction(){
        if(this.isMobile){ //calculated via another function based on breakpoints that returns true
            for (let i = 0; i < this.parent.length; i++) {
                this.parent[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.addChildrenActive(i)
                });
                this.parent[i].removeEventListener('mouseover', this.addChildrenActive(i));
                this.parent[i].removeEventListener('mouseout', this.addChildrenActive(i));
                
            }
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.parent.length; i++) {
                this.parent[i].addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
                    this.addChildrenActive(i)
                });
                 this.parent[i].addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
                    this.addChildrenActive(i)
                });
            }
        }
  }
```

The removeEventListeners when isMobile is not woking for me and I'm currently able to hover and click to show the dropdown. How should I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't remove a listener when an anonymous function was attached to the event. Use named function instead. And drop the loop, you can't use `i` inside the listener, the value won't be what you think it is. If you need a one-off listener, use [once parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters).

Comment: sounds reasonable but confusing! would you mind writing some code so I know what you're talking about specifically? thank you! @Teemu

Comment: instead of `this.addChildrenActive(i)` try `this.addChildrenActive(e.target)`

Comment: not working @SimoneRossaini :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Teemu indicated you have to use a named function because you need a reference to that function if you want to remove it from a listener.

So instead of writing an anonymous function inside the `addEventListener()` you supply it the name of a function you defined elsewhere - and most importantly not inside your loop.

For example:

```
parent[i].addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    this.addChildrenActive(i)
});
```

becomes

```
parent[i].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverHandler);
```

and it's named function

```
function mouseOverHandler(e)
{
  console.log("mouse over", e.currentTarget);
}
```

You might have noticed the `e` parameter inside the function. This will be populated with data related to the event e.g. the name of the event or which element caused it.

This listener can then be removed using:

```
parent[i].removeEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverHandler);
```

Let me give you a more complete example:

```js
class Navigation {
  constructor() {
    this.isMobile = false;
    this.parent = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    this.navbarInteraction();
  }

  navbarInteraction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.parent.length; i++) {
      this.parent[i].removeEventListener('mouseover', this.addChildrenActive);
      this.parent[i].removeEventListener('click', this.addChildrenActive);
      if (this.isMobile) {
        this.parent[i].addEventListener('click', this.addChildrenActive);
      } else {
        this.parent[i].addEventListener('mouseover', this.addChildrenActive);
      }
    }
  }

  addChildrenActive(e) {
    console.log("addChildrenActive()", e.currentTarget, e.type);
  }
}

let navigation = new Navigation();
```

```html
<div id="divA">DIV1</div>
<div id="divB">DIV2</div>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="navigation.isMobile=this.checked;navigation.navbarInteraction();">
<span>isMobile</span>
```

Comment: how is this applicable in ES6, though, @obscure? addChildrenActive is not defined, this. addChildrenActive() currentTarget is not defined and this.addChildrenActive(e) e is not defined. Going crazy with this one, tbh. Tried this.parent[i].addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {this.mouseOverHandler(e)}); and works, but the removeEventListener is not working this way

Comment: This should work without trouble. How did you add the `addChildrenActive()` function? Is the code in your question part of a class definition? By the way - get rid of the `(e) => { //some code inside }`. This way you're creating an anonymous function again - not a named. Just keep the `//some code inside`.

Comment: yes, @obscure, all functions are part of a class definition

Comment: Then for testing purposes try adding the listener like `this.parent[i].addEventListener('click', this.addChildrenActive);` and add the function inside your class' scope like `addChildrenActive(e) {
    console.log("addChildrenActive()", e.currentTarget, e.type);
}`

Comment: I've modified the example in my answer to take use of a class instead if that helps.